# Why does this oscillator circuit work well in the simulator, but not in the real implementation?

Tags: rf, analog, bjt, oscillator, simulation

I want to build a 10MHz sine wave oscillator using a simple BC546 BJT.

This is my schematic and its Multisim simulation:

[image]

You can see I am getting around 10.5MHz quite well. When I build this circuit
on perfboard, I get no output on the oscilloscope. It simply doesn't work.

How can it be possible? Is the simulation wrong, or am I missing something?

Comment: well your capacitor values are pretty small (single digit picofarads) which means your circuit is susceptible to stray capacitance and inductance from other places, like the perfboard itself - no comment on any other part of the circuit, but I imagine someone experienced in that will be along soon. A picture of the circuit you made would probably be helpful

Comment: Look at the peak-peak value of your simulation: `12.021 - 11.986 = 35 mV`. That output capacitor looks very flimsy... better make it several orders of magnitude larger. Also, those 4 pF caps are likely larger on the breadboard.

Comment: Did you add a decoupling supply capacitor ?

Comment: Lower the inductor to 10 uH and make c1, c2 , c7 to 12p, 5p, 15p. R4 // 7 pF which is the capacitance of a test probe of 10Meg. You should measure ~ 6 Vpp at output.

Comment: C1 is probably not a physical component, but a parasitic capacitancr of the inductor

Comment: @tobalt C1 is real capacitor which I connected. It's the schematic which I built.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen You are talking about differences between two peaks. The voltage output range is 24 V p-p, which is very high.

Comment: @BeB00 Single digit picoFarad needed for that high frequency.

Comment: @Sonali then expect another 5-10 pF of parasitic capacitance in parallel to the inductor. By adding more capacitance, you push the self resonance frequency even lower.

Comment: @Antonio51 Presently as you can see, the output is 23Vpp.

Comment: @Sonali it doesn't matter what the output of the sim is. Your real output is ~ zero. likely because your oscillation frequency is way lower than your high pass frequency..You got several good suggestions.

Comment: @tobalt Are you talking about the C2-R4 high pass ?

Comment: yes @Sonali 10 MHz highpass is needlessly high for a 10 Mhz oscillator.

Comment: @tobalt C2 = 1pF and R4 = 99k, so cuttoff freq is around 1.6 MHz, which is quite below the 10MHz requirement.

Comment: @Antonio51 Making L1 = 10uH, C1 = 12pF, C2 = 5pF and C7 = 15pF, gives 7.4 Vpp on simulator. What is the gain? Earlier I was getting 23Vpp on simulator.

Comment: @Sonaly In the real live, you must add at the output the impedance of the probe (7pF//10Meg). So, you have only ~ 23/8 = 3v volts in fact.

Comment: @Antonio51 How did you get the factor 8, from 7pF//10M ?

Comment: 1pf/(1pf+7pf) ... low value of capacitor has higher impedance ...

Answer (score 1):

Your very low output on the sim is a red flag. More feedback is needed. Get more volts on the sim with a lossy tank coil and parasitic capacitances. Do bypass the base to ground and the PSU rail to ground with 100nF ceramic         caps. Your model on the sim may be better than real device and your tank has losses. So it just runs on the sim and just does not in real life.

Comment: Output is not low. Just look. It's around 23V p-p.

Answer (score 1):

By lowering the value of impedances (L1,C1,C2, and C7),
you can get a higher voltage at output (don't forget the "always" capacitive load, as a probe x10).

As already said, don't forget decoupling capacitor ...
Don't forget also that "breadboard" has also some "non negligeable" capacitors between plates ...)

[image]

Comment: I would still decrease L1 and increase C1. The parasitic capacitance of physically small inductors in the µH range is probably in the ballpark of 10 pF.

Comment: Agree. It was only to show to OP that "parasitics" (capacitors for example), as in this case, must be taken into account ...